# fopen can't create file

Tags: php, fopen

I’m working on something which requires PHP to make files and folders. I'm using `fopen` to create the file. However, it doesn't seem to work. When I was writing the code, I was on windows with WAMP and everything was working but when I moved the site to Ubuntu server the script simply doesn't work.

This is the code I’m using for the creation on the file and the ziping

```
mkdir($sessionid, 777);

// create the server.properties
$server_config = fopen("$sessionid/server.properties",'a');
$config = "test";
fwrite($server_config,$config);
fclose($server_config);

// create the run.sh/bat
$server_script = fopen("$sessionid/RUN.$platform", 'a');
fwrite($server_script,$script);
fclose($server_script);

// zip them all together
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$ow = 1;
$file= "$sessionid/RFSLABSserver.zip";
if($zip->open($file,$ow?ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE:ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===TRUE)
{
    // Add the files to the .zip file
    $zip->addFile("/$sessionid/server.properties", "server.properties");   
    $zip->addFIle("/$sessionid/RUN.$platform", "Start.$platform");
    // file source as file name

    $zip->close();
}
```

What the script does is to create a folder with the sessionid which is a random number and inside that folder create the 2 files and zip them. Note the folder is created but not the files inside

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try setting proper permissions for directory.

```
mkdir($sessionid, 777);
```

is wrong, you should write

```
mkdir($sessionid, 0777);
```

Comment: why? whats the problem with that?

Comment: Don't know. I'm not the Linux expert. But I had such hosting and I cannot create any file in folder if It had permissions lower than 777

Comment: @JakeGould Even if I create in this directory .htaccess with IndexIgnore * Deny from all  ?

Answer (score 3):

Your script has this:

```
mkdir($sessionid, 777);
```

But it should be this; note the `0` in front of `777`:

```
mkdir($sessionid, 0777);
```

That said, you should read up on PHP & Unix permissions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php). In general, your permissions should *never ever* for any reason be set to `777`.

When you set permissions to `777` it means that 100% anyone with access to your machine on any level can `read`, `write` & `execute` the file. Meaning if your site gets hacked, a hacker than then use the execute permissions to launch scripts to get deeper in your system. Or someone else on the system—since they can `read`, `write` & `execute` the file—can simply delete your files without you ever knowing.

You should instead see who is the *owner* of the directory you are trying to create `$sessionid` in. The owner of the file or directory/folder is the key to solving issues like this. Then `chmod` permissions need to conform to the needs of the file owner.

The owner of the parent directory where you are trying to do this should be the same as the Apache web server user which is usually `www-data` on modern systems.  So that parent folder you are attempting to create the `$sessionid` file in should be owned by `www-data` and have `read`, `write` & `execute` permissions set which equates to `7`.

A more safe, sane & practical thing to do—once you have the owner issue set—is to set the permissions to that parent folder to `755` and set your `mkdir` to `0755` as well like this:

```
mkdir($sessionid, 0755);
```

Setting directories to `755` and setting files to `644`  is the best way to go as long as the ownership of the file is solid & correct. `644` permissions basically break down as follows

- The first `6` means the owner of the file can `read` & `write` to it.
- The next `4` means members of the group connected to that file can only `read` it.
- The next `4` means others—who are neither the owner or a member of the group—can `read` it.

As for `755` they are best for directories/folders because directories/folders need to have `execute` rights to allow you to view the contents inside of them.  So it breaks down like this:

- The first `7` means the owner of the file can `read`, `write` & `execute` it.
- The next `5` means members of the group connected to that directory/folder can only `read` & `execute` it.
- The next `5` means others—who are neither the owner or a member of the group—can can only `read` & `execute` it.