# Set permission to create a folder that contains a website

Tags: linux, webserver, file-permissions

I am creating a folder to have my website in it. How do I add permission to create this folder?

```
MKDIR 777 MyWebSite
```

Will give `R`ear, `W`rite & e`X`ecute access to everyone.

So what is the best set of permission that i should use when creating this folder ?

Comment: You should not give 777 rights to the whole web root directory. Instead you should give may be 444 to the web root directory and 777 to specific directories e.g., `uploads` if there are going to be any.

Comment: @OzairKafray: No-one can access the files in the directory unless you give them x (search) permision. Thus, you should set 555 rather than 444, permission, though you should consider 500 or 550 too. The 777 permission should be used extremely sparingly.  It might be sensible to use 733 permission in the uploads directory; people can create files in the directory, but can't access them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a web document root, the best permissions are `755` for directories/folders & `644` for files. The key is making sure the directories/folders as well as the files are owned by the same user connected to the web server. Which in Linux systems is usually `www-data`. I actually gave a fairly detailed explanation on why `777` permissions are not good for any reason [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567911/fopen-cant-create-file/23568196#23568196) and here is an edited version for your question.

When you set permissions to `777` it means that 100% anyone with access to your machine on any level can `read`, `write` & `execute` the file. Meaning if your site gets hacked, a hacker than then use the execute permissions to launch scripts to get deeper in your system. Or someone else on the system—since they can `read`, `write` & `execute` the file—can simply delete your files without you ever knowing.

Setting directories to `755` and setting files to `644` is the best way to go as long as the ownership of the file is solid & correct. `644` permissions basically break down as follows:

- The first `6` means the owner of the file can `read` & `write` to it.
- The next `4` means members of the group connected to that file can only `read` it.
- The next `4` means others—who are neither the owner or a member of the group—can `read` it.

As for `755` they are best for directories/folders because directories/folders need to have `execute` rights to allow you to view the contents inside of them. So it breaks down like this:

- The first `7` means the owner of the file can `read`, `write` & `execute` it.
- The next `5` means members of the group connected to that directory/folder can only `read` & `execute` it.
- The next `5` means others—who are neither the owner or a member of the group—can can only `read` & `execute` it.

Answer (score 2):

Best is `755` for everything (dirs) `644` for files.   Some directories (like `uploads` in WordPress) need to have `777` as any user can send file there. But that BIG permission should be set only for such directory not for everything. Normally READ for files and execute for dirs (with read) would be enought for almost any directory and file (only that upload dirs needs more).

Comment: It realy depends on the users you are using - so its better to write that - but as i said - 1st set 755 and 644 - then if something is not working you may change some dirs and files to 777 an 666 - this question was only about permissions - not about users and groups - therefore i will not discuss this kind of answers as it would be muuuch longer and almost copy from the permission and user&groups documentation.

Comment: Yes, but sometime that local users is web user too - and im well avare hwo it work exactly - how ever i dont have so great english languager skill to describe it as the ,,acceptedd'' answer got - still - its good.